# How to filter a list by semi-unique values

Tags: python

I have a dataset which I need to filter for "unique" occurrences. Basically, I want to remove each line where the same product is purchased by the same user more than once in a day, regardless of the variable device. In case of multiple occurrences, I which to keep only the first line.

The data:

```
datetime, device, product, user

  [
  ['2013-07-08 15:00:00', 'pc',       'X',        'A'],
  ['2013-07-09 17:00:00', 'pc',       'X',        'A'],
  ['2013-07-09 10:00:00', 'andr',     'Y',        'B'],
  ['2013-07-10 18:00:00', 'pc',       'Y',        'B'],
  ['2013-07-10 21:00:00', 'ipho',     'Y',        'B'],       <- second occurance of B getting Y that day
  ['2013-07-10 22:00:00', 'andr',     'Y',        'B'],       <- third occurance of B getting Y that day
  ['2013-07-10 02:00:00', 'ipho',     'Z',        'C'],
  ['2013-07-10 11:00:00', 'pc',       'Z',        'C']        <- second occurance of C getting Z that day
  ]
```

Which should be filtered to:

```
  ['2013-07-08 15:00:00', 'pc',       'X',        'A'],
  ['2013-07-09 17:00:00', 'pc',       'X',        'A'],
  ['2013-07-09 10:00:00', 'andr',     'Y',        'B'],
  ['2013-07-10 18:00:00', 'pc',       'Y',        'B'],
  ['2013-07-10 02:00:00', 'ipho',     'Z',        'C'],
  ['2013-07-10 11:00:00', 'pc',       'Z',        'C']
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strip the time part from the datetime, then store each item in a dictionary, if it is not already there. As key to the dictionary use a tuple of date, product, user.

E.g.

```
 d = {}
 for datetime, device, product, user in table:
     date = datetime[:10]
     if (date, product, user) not in d:
         d[(date, product, user)] = [datetime, device, product, user]
```